# Cannot post question

Tags: discussion, support

I am trying to post this question, which appears to be formatted properly:

---

[image]

---

But I cannot, because the site says:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
> code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button
> or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?]
> toolbar icon.

I saw other posts about this on meta, but none solved the problem. What can I do about this?

Comment: Try posting the LaTeX part as code for the time being, and someone else can edit it so that it displays with MathJax.

Comment: Thanks! How can someone else do it if the author can't?

Comment: Does it not proceed to post successfully if you follow the suggested instructions "Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut." for the LaTeX part of your post?

Comment: I don't have the question anymore... Probably it would. I don't remember reading that part of the instructions, sorry.